# What does the letter "B" stand for in webapps.stackexchange.com's favicon?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm just curious. Why "B"?

"We **b**" or "**B** eta" or something else?

Comment: Normally I can use SO sites without my glasses, but I had to put them on to see what you were talking about. Without them it just looks like a filled square.

Comment: Hmm.  Chrome didn't load the favicon.  Had to switch over to FF to see it.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome (Windows and Mac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta, but this is subject to change.